# "Name or service not known" with mail-merged ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I am writing a bash script which (in addition to other, more interesting things) executes a series of commands on remote hosts, however the ssh command fails with "Name or service not known". The following script reproduces the behaviour:

```
#!/bin/bash

function apply {
    local cmd_template cmd_arg logfile
    cmd_template=$1
    cmd_arg=$2
    logfile=$3
    local cmd

    cmd=${cmd_template//'{}'/${cmd_arg}}
    echo "cmd is ${cmd}"
    ${cmd} >${logfile} 2>&1
}

USER="symcbean"
HOST="ssh.example.com"
SCRIPT="sleep"
TEMPLATE="ssh \"${USER}@${HOST}\" \"${SCRIPT}\" {}"

apply "${TEMPLATE}" "1" "/tmp/test.$$"
```

Output:

```
cmd is ssh "symcbean@ssh.example.com" "sleep" 1
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ssh.example.com": Name or service not known
```

However DNS is present and valid. Further, if I copy and paste the ssh command from the output, it works as expected.

What am I missing here?

(Before anyone suggests I just use xargs or parallel - the actual implementation requires behaviour not present in these).

Comment: (Scalar) variables are for data. Don't try to cram a command line into a scalar variable. Either use an array, with one element per item, or else a function

Comment: Have you tried passing arrays as function arguments in bash? However the values here are all scalars. iterating over multiple values is not a problem - it is dereferencing the variables into a command string ssh will understand which is a problem.

Comment: Exactly. And that's why you'll find answers to other questions here on U&L that say "don't do that; instead, use an array".  Oh, as an aside take care using all-capital variable names. You're already overloading `$USER` and there may be others you unintentionally hit. Better to use lowercase (or mixed)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the clue is in the error message:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ssh.example.com": Name or service not known
```

Note the unmatched double quote.

ssh is splitting "username@host" into `"username` and `host"`. The solution was to remove the quoting around this in TEMPLATE=

This does mean the script won't work if the username contains a space - but that is an acceptable compromise (since such a scenario would likely have lots of other impacts).

I suspect that I could have been creative with `eval` to solve the problem here, but due to the way this appears in my implementation this would create other issues.